# Rotate MKAnnotation image not title

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I am trying to rotate an image for a MKAnnotation and while I succeed to do so, the title of it is also rotating. Is there a way to keep the title straight? Any help would be really appreciated!

Here is my code:

In `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let middlePoint = CustomPointAnnotation()
middlePoint.coordinate = self.coordinates
middlePoint.imageName = "routemiddle"
middlePoint.title = "\(hourDetailedRoute):\(minuteDetailedRoute)"
middlePoint.courseDegrees = self.vehicleChangeCourse
self.mapa.addAnnotation(middlePoint)
```

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "annotation"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView!.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        anView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation
    anView!.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)
    anView!.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.mapa.transform, CGFloat(degreesToRadians(cpa.courseDegrees)))

    return anView
}
```

```
class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var imageName: String!
    var courseDegrees = 0.0
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out! I just needed to rotate only the image instead of rotating the whole view.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "annotation"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView!.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        anView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation
    var imagePin = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)
    imagePin = imagePin?.rotateImage(cpa.courseDegrees)
    anView!.image = imagePin

    return anView
}
```